# xsl any symbol code for value comparison using <xsl:when test

Tags: html, xslt

I was wondering what would be any symbol code?

```
<xsl:when test="path/path1 = '(ANYSYMBOL)1' ">
```

this code alows us to check if some values equals X1,@1,%1,91....

so what is the anysymbol/ anychar code @xxx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such wildcards.

You have two options:

```
<xsl:when test="substring(path/path1, 2) = '1'">
```

and

```
<xsl:when test="matches(path/path1, '.1')">
```

The latter one using regexp is only XSLT 2.0 compatible.

Comment: substring function is engenious :)